# Neater way of checking if number is within two numbers, and changing it if not

Tags: python

I'm just curious if there's a better way to do this than individual checks. It's not a problem, but I'm guessing there's probably a more concise way of doing it.

```
inputNumber = 1.2

if ( type( inputNumber ) == float or type( inputNumber ) == int ) or str( inputNumber ).isdigit():
    number = float( inputNumber )

    if not 0 < number < 1:
        print "Number must be between 0 and 1, changing it to fit within the limits"

    if number > 1:
        number = 1.0
    elif number < 0:
        number = 0.0
else:
    print "Invalid input"
```

Comment: `number = min(1.0, max(0.0, number))` is shorter, but I think your way is easier to understand.

Comment: Ooh thanks, that's really useful to know, my way is easier to understand but with multiple checks it gets very messy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking for types. Just try to convert and handle any exception that might occur:

```
try:
  number = float(inputNumber)
except ValueError:
  print("could not convert to float")
```

The check if the number is within your desired range is already as pythonic as it gets. To constrain a number to a given range, you could use

```
number = min(1, max(0, number))
```

but one can argue if this is more readable than your approach.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this is probably the way I was looking for (unless there's an even better way that someone suggests later) :)  I also forgot about try/except being better, so I'll change some bits of my code for that too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html):

```
from numbers import Number
from warnings import warn # prints to STDERR instead of STDOUT

input_number = 1.2

if not isinstance(input_number, Number):
    warn("Number must be between 0 and 1, changing it to fit within the limits")
    input_number = min(1.0, max(0.0, float(input_number))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the checking it's a number is useful to know, even if it's better using try/except for it :)